# Sound downloader for both YouTube and Facebook videos

Tags: windows, gratis, mp3

Which software can be used to extract MP3 sound from both Facebook videos and YouTube videos?

It must run on Windows and be gratis.

Comment: So you only need sound, right? What OS (because they are not always browser based), what price? Please edit your question.

Comment: Foe windows and must be free of cost i found https://fvdtube.com/facebook-video-downloader/ and https://fvdtube.com/en/youtube-mp3-converter/ for both youtube and facebook !! Could you please guide is it safe or i should try some paid one ?

Answer (score 2):

Youtube-DL (https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) should fit the bill.

- Despite the name, it downloads videos [from a gazillion sites](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/supportedsites.html), among them (obviously) Youtube and FaceBook.
- Usually downloads complete video with audio, but can download only audio (command line switch `--extract-audio`).
- While it is a command-line program (specifially, a Python program), it is fully supported on Windows, and a Windows executable is provided (see homepage link above)
- It is gratis (actually, free software, specifically [Unlicense](http://unlicense.org/)).

Note: To use option `--extract-audio`, you need to install [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/), too. Just download an exe and put it into the folder of youtube-dl. See e.g. https://satuimrambles.wordpress.com/2016/09/27/how-to-install-youtube-dl-ffmpeg-and-rtmpdump-on-windowsmaclinux/ for details.